# move custom fields to antoher wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I made custom fields by Advanced custom field. But it was a lot of work and a lot of fields so **how can i move all of this to another WordPress site?**

Answer (score 0):

I knew it. 
just click tools in acf menu. then you will find that you can export them as json then import them again from this json file